# Generating db script with SubSonic /version command

Tags: subsonic, internationalization

I am using SubSonic version 2.2 to generate a script of my database using the /version command. Recently, I needed to generate a script for a database which is set to French collation and running on a French OS. The script fails because there are several columns which are of datatype "float" which use a comma instead of a period. (2,3 instead of 2.3). When I try to execute the sql script to re-import the data this causes an error. (column mismatch as the db engine thinks I am trying to insert too many columns). Is there any way to get the /version command to support internationalization? Is this supported in version 3? Modifying the original data is not an option unfortunately.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably for this issue your best bet is to use Visual Studio and right-click on your DB selecting "Publish To Provider" - this generates the scripts for you (data too).

Sort of stuck on this one and no - 3.0 doesn't address this.

Comment: Thanks Rob. It works using VS 2008. I didn't even know that feature existed and this project is in VS 2005 (with all the SubSonic commands already configured) so it never even occurred to me to look. You learn something new every day...